# What am i doing wrong? it wont run thru every condition

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to have someone guess a number from 1 to 6. I give them two tries if, by the end of the second try, they don't get it, then else will tell them what the number is but it just won't run. what am I doing wrong?

```js
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() *6) +1;
var answer = false;

var guess = prompt('Take a guess, pick a number from 1 to 6');
if(parseInt(guess) === number) {
  answer === true;
} else if (parseInt(guess) > number) {
  var guessLess = prompt('To high! Guess less');
  if (parseInt(guessLess) === number) {
    answer === true;
  } else if (parseInt(guess) < number) {
    var guessMore = prompt('Guess more');
      if(parseInt(guessMore) === number) {   
        answer = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (answer) {
    alert('You got it')
  } else {
    alert('No. The number was ' + number);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have those things: `answer === true;` ?

Comment: On every line that does not contain the word `if`, change `===` to `=`

Comment: You may also want to check if number === NaN if they write "one" it will not parse. You need to think of everything the end user will try and create a condition for it

Comment: yes whenever i input a "1" and it shoots straight to my else statement and skips the else if . How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using comparison instead of assignment in the below segment

```js
if (parseInt(guessLess) === number) {
   answer === true;
```

Change it to

```js
if (parseInt(guessLess) === number) {
   answer = true;
```